# How can I find the sum of this product?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Title says it all, really. I'm struggling to find the sum of the following equation.

$\sum_{k=2}^nk*(k-1)*{n \choose k}$

I believe I should simplify to $\sum_{k=2}^n[k^2{n \choose k}-k{n \choose k}]$, but I'm not sure where to go after that. I know from another question that $\sum_{k=0}^nk^2{n \choose k}=2^{n-1}(n^2+n)$, if that helps.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different hints:
**Hint1:** What happens if you take the second derivative of $(x+1)^n?$ using the binomial theorem?
**Hint2:** $$\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{j}=\binom{n}{j}\binom{n-j}{k-j}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another variation is to use the binomial identity
\begin{align*}
k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=2}^nk(k-1)\binom{n}{k}&=n\sum_{k=2}^n(k-1)\binom{n-1}{k-1}\\
> &=n(n-1)\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n-2}{k-2}\\
> &=n(n-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{k}\tag{1}\\
> &=n(n-1)2^{n-2}
> \end{align*}

In (1) we shift the index $k$ to start from $k=0$.